# MySQL Что правильнее/быстрее: подзапрос в основном запросе или связка всех таблиц с группировкой?

Tags: mysql

Создал 2 разных запроса к базе MySQL. Оба запроса выводят одинаковый результат, но работают по разному. Хочется понять, какой из запросов более правильный/быстрый. Буду рад любым комментариям.

**Запрос 1:**

```sql
SELECT o.id, o.status_pay, o.status_order, o.comments, o.user_info, u.id,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Shop_orders_goods WHERE order_id=o.id AND warehouse_id IN (1,2)) w  
FROM Shop_orders o 
  LEFT JOIN Users u ON o.user_id=u.id 
HAVING w>0 
ORDER BY o.date DESC;
```

EXPLAIN

```
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys             | key     | key_len | ref                   | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | o     | ALL    | NULL                      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                  | 17891 | Using filesort           |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                   | PRIMARY | 4       | mydanceshop.o.user_id |     1 | Using index              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | g     | ref    | order_id,warehouse_id,o_w | o_w     | 4       | mydanceshop.o.id      |     2 | Using where; Using index |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+--------------------------+
```

**Запрос 2:**

```sql
SELECT o.id, o.status_pay, o.status_order, o.comments, o.user_info, u.id 
FROM Shop_orders o 
  LEFT JOIN Users u ON o.user_id=u.id
  , Shop_orders_goods g 
WHERE o.id=g.order_id 
  AND g.warehouse_id IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY o.id 
ORDER BY o.date DESC;
```

EXPLAIN

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys             | key     | key_len | ref                   | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | ALL    | PRIMARY                   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                  | 17891 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                   | PRIMARY | 4       | mydanceshop.o.user_id |     1 | Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | g     | ref    | order_id,warehouse_id,o_w | o_w     | 4       | mydanceshop.o.id      |     2 | Using where; Using index        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Я не силен в синтаксисе оператора EXPLAIN, но второй запрос мне показался более медленным из-за создания временной таблицы для хранения результата (Using temporary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если судить по Explain, то первый вариант будет оптимальнее.
Второй вариант приводит еще и к созданию промежуточных таблиц, что замедлит работу.

Но в общем плане оба запроса не оптимальны, т.к. таблица `Shop_orders` перебирается полностью без всяких индексов.

Плюс даже без индексов Вы можете оптимизировать запросы, т.к. сейчас они слишком усложнены.

Запрос 1: можно легко обойтись без having (его лучше вообще избегать):

```sql
SELECT o.id,o.status_pay,o.status_order,o.comments,o.user_info,u.id
FROM Shop_orders o 
LEFT JOIN Users u ON o.user_id=u.id 
where exists(select 1 from Shop_orders_goods WHERE order_id=o.id AND warehouse_id IN (1,2))
ORDER BY o.date DESC;
```

Запрос 2: его надо перевести на нормальный join и все:

```sql
SELECT o.id,o.status_pay,o.status_order,o.comments,o.user_info,u.id 
FROM Shop_orders o 
JOIN Shop_orders_goods g ON o.id=g.order_id AND g.warehouse_id IN (1,2)
LEFT JOIN Users u ON o.user_id=u.id
GROUP BY o.id 
ORDER BY o.date DESC;
```

Во втором запросе стоит убрать GROUP BY и заменить его на distinct, т.к. индекс по ID, даже если он есть, в данном случае не будет никогда использоваться, и лишняя группировка может привести к доп. ненужной нагрузке, если Вам подсчитывать реально ничего не надо.

Теоретически второй вариант должен быть предпочтительнее, но, как я сказал ранее, для начала надо разобраться с индексами и подумать, как их можно улучшить.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень доходчиво все объяснили. Как таблица `Shop_orders` может перебираться по индексам, если запрос идет ко всем записям?

Comment: @mr.Mouse ну если брать некий, возможно отдаленный пример, если в `Shop_orders_goods` гораздо меньшее количество записей по заданным условиям. Тогда может быть выбрано, допустим, 1000 записей, а дальше уже для этих записей по первичному ключу может быть выбрано все из таблицы `Shop_orders`. Но все это можно понять, только зная точно размеры таблиц и дальше частично опытным путем сделать наиболее оптимальный запрос и составить индексы.

Comment: В таблице `Shop_orders_goods` примерно в 10 раз больше записей, чем в `Shop_orders`. Таблица `Shop_orders` - данные по заказу (номер заказа, покупатель и т.п), `Shop_orders_goods` - таблица с товарами, в этой таблице есть поле `warehous_id` - это склад с которого отгружен товар. Так вот нужно было сделать запрос на выборку заказов, в которых есть товары, отгруженные с определенных складов

Comment: А количество товаров, отгруженных с 2 складов, сколько ориентировачно? Если меньше нескольких тысяч, то есть смысл сделать индекс по warehouse_id, проверить, что он используется, потом сделать join Shop_orders без всяких группировок, и посмотреть, как в таком случае начинает весть себя оптимизатор. Если все ок, и индексы используются без полного перебора, добавлять оставшиеся части запроса с проверкой по explain, т.к. бывают некоторые неожиданные мелочи, которые резко ломают оптимальный план выполнения.

Comment: Записей больше 8000 по каждому складу. Попробую сделать от обратного, как вы советовали. Еще раз спасибо!